# Maximum value for textSize() with Processing 3.3.7

Tags: java, processing

I am actually trying to draw a big message with `Processing 3.3.7` but the `textSize()` function does not work as expected. The sketch is empty.

```
void setup()
{
    size(600, 600);

    background(0);
    fill(#CC0000);

    textSize(150);
    text("Yeah!", width/2, height/2, 80, 80);
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the definition of [`text`](https://processing.org/reference/text_.html) is this:

> ```
> text(str, x1, y1, x2, y2)
> ```
>
> - x1 float: by default, the x-coordinate of text, see rectMode() for more info
> - y1 float: by default, the y-coordinate of text, see rectMode() for more info
> - x2 float: by default, the width of the text box, see rectMode() for more info
> - y2 float: by default, the height of the text box, see rectMode() for more info

---

The width and height of the text box which you have choosen (`80, 80`) is too small to display a text in fontsize `150`, increasing the width and height of the text box will make larger texts appear aswell.

---

Also if you want to center the text (`width/2` is the x starting point of drawing) you should subtract it with half the `textWidth` to compensate for the size of the text.

To compensate for height there's this "*adding the textAscent() and textDescent() values will give you the total height of the line.*" [source](https://processing.org/reference/textAscent_.html).

```
text("Yeah!", width/2-textWidth("Yeah!")/2, 
        height/2-(textAscent() + textDescent())/2, 150, 150);
```

Comment: What function using for compensate the height?

Comment: @Henaerts `height/2-(textAscent() + textDescent())/2` "*Adding the textAscent() and textDescent() values will give you the total height of the line.*" [source](https://processing.org/reference/textAscent_.html)